# Newb pact JVM provider

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

Hope someone might be able to help me, been beating my head against the wall for a while and can't seem to break through.  I have tried following multiple examples and doing endless searching, just can't seem to find out what I am missing.  There are a lot of examples to follow but most are spring applications and I know nothing about spring so I don't know if I am trying to mix spring with non-spring code...

This is NOT a spring application nor do I want it to be.  I am trying to get this going as just a simple java producer verification.  Pretty much as simple as it can be...

I have a good contract and I am able to get a successful verification of the contract using JS but want to use JAVA.

I have way too many imports in my code but don't know at this point which ones are not important and or are duplications.

I have a few compile errors but can't seem to find out how to resolve.  I noted the compile errors in the code.  I think I am close but just don't know at this point.

Is the pactTestTemplate method the one that actually does the contract verification?  So that is the method I would call from my unit test?  Really confused at this point as to all the magic that is going on in the background...

If you made it this far, thanks...

```
package testWorkContract;

import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.*;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationContext;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactUrl;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.HttpTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.Target;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.TestTarget;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.*;


@PactFolder("/temp/pacts")
@RunWith(PactRunner.class) // Say JUnit to run tests with custom Runner
@Provider("work") // Set up name of tested provider
public class PactProvider {

    @TestTarget // Annotation denotes Target that will be used for tests
    public final HttpsTestTarget target = new HttpsTestTarget("127.0.0.1", 443);

    @BeforeClass // Method will be run once: before whole contract test suite
    public static void setUpService() {
    }

    @Before // Method will be run before each test of interaction
    public void before() {
    }

    // JUST A QUICK TEST METHOD TO MAKE SURE MY UNIT TEST CAN WORK...
    public int testService() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    @TestTemplate   // THIS IS AN ERROR, CAN'T FIND @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void pactTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) {
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }

}
```

Here are my dependencies, first time setting up maven also so there might be problems there:

```
    <properties>
        <json-schema-validator.version>3.3.0</json-schema-validator.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <pact.version>4.0.10</pact.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${pact.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${pact.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${pact.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past my problems.  I was thinking about this incorrectly.  The code I was trying to write SHOULD HAVE BEEN THE ACTUAL JUNIT test.  I was trying to write a junit test that then called the class I was trying to put together.

This is the junit test I ended up with for starters

```
package testWorkContract;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestTemplate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

//import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.annotations.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactSource;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.HttpsTestTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationContext;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider;
import junit.framework.Assert;

@Provider("work")
@PactFolder("/temp/pacts")

public class PactProviderTest {

      @BeforeEach
      void before(PactVerificationContext context) {
//      context.setTarget(HttpTestTarget.fromUrl(new URL(myProviderUrl)));
        // or something like
         context.setTarget(new HttpsTestTarget("localhost", 443, "/", true));
      }
      
      @Test
        @TestTemplate
        @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
        void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
          context.verifyInteraction();
        }

}
```

and this is the pom file

```
    <properties>
        <json-schema-validator.version>3.3.0</json-schema-validator.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <pact.version>4.0.10</pact.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-consumer-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${pact.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${pact.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${pact.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
        
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                
            <plugin>
                <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.11</version>
                <configuration>
                  <serviceProviders>
                    <!-- You can define as many as you need, but each must have a unique name -->
                    <serviceProvider>
                      <name>work</name>
                      <!-- All the provider properties are optional, and have sensible defaults (shown below) -->
                      <protocol>https</protocol>
                      <host>localhost</host>
                      <port>443</port>
                      <path>/</path>
                      <insecure>true</insecure>
                      <pactFileDirectories>
                      
                                  <pactFileDirectory>/temp/pacts</pactFileDirectory>
                      </pactFileDirectories>
                      
                    </serviceProvider>
                  </serviceProviders>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
        </build>
```